# Increasing rowspan in table column decreases width of it

Tags: html, css

I've made a table with two rows of which first has 3 columns and second has 2 (see code snippet). The middle column in the first row has `rowspan="2"`. The problem is that it gets smaller than its width is set.

```css
.kolona {
  background: white;
  height: auto !important;
}
td { width: 100%; }
#langas td { border: 1px solid black; }
#langas { border: 1px solid black; }
#langas td td { /* empty */ }
.lightblue { background-color: lightblue; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td { width: auto; }
table table {
  height: 100%;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#langas tbody { border-spacing: 2px; }
tbody {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-table;
  border-collapse: initial;
}
.bb { height: 30px; }
.img-bg {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* background: no-repeat url( data url ); */
  z-index: 555;
}
.window-col {
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
tr { /* empty */ }
.kampuciai .kampuciai-bf:before {
  background: #000;
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  width: 1px;
}
.kampuciai .kampuciai-bf:after {
  background: #000;
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  width: 1px;
}
.kampuciai {
  padding: 5px;
}
.kampuciai:before {
  background: #000;
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
  width: 1px;
}
.kampuciai:after {
  background: #000;
  content: "";
  width: 2px;
  height: 11px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  right: 3px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  transform: rotateZ(45deg);
  width: 1px;
}
#langas tbody tbody td {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.top-units {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
* { /* empty */ }
.frame-units .units {
  background-color: #ededed;
  max-width: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}
.top-units .units { text-align: center; }
.top-units td {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
}
.top-units td:first-child { border: none; }
.frame-units .unit-block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.main-unit-block-width .units, .main-unit-block-height .units {
  width: 70px;
  max-width: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.top-units .units { text-align: center; }
.frame-units .units {
  background-color: #ededed;
  max-width: 60px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  color: #000;
}
#t_width, #r_height { width: 39px; }
.frame-units .u-bubble {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 30px;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  text-align: right;
}
.frame-units .units .unit { margin-left: 4px; }
.upper-measures, .upper-measures tbody, .upper-measures tbody tbody {
  border-collapse: collapse!important;
}
#langas tbody tbody { height: 100%; }
  .right-units {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
/* .right-units td { background: url( absolute url ) repeat-y 15px top; } */
.right-units table tr:last-child td { border: none; }
.right-units table td { border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
.right-units .unit-block { /* empty */ }
.right-units .units {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.varstymas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.bb td { border:1px solid black; }
.bb { height: 100%; }
.paskutinis-borderis { padding: 5px; }
.duru-img { width: 100%; }
.kolonos-plotis:disabled { background: #ededed; }
.kolonos-aukstis:disabled { background: #ededed; }
.inputErr { border: 1px solid red; }
.st0 { fill:#AFB2B4; }
```

```html
<table id="langas" style="height: 302px; width: 302px;">
  <tbody style="height: 300px; width: 300px;">
    <tr id="window-row-0" class="window-row">
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="window-col" style="padding: 0px;height:150px;line-height:0px;width:100px;" id="window-col-0-0">
        <div id="img-bg-0" class="img-bg"></div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="1" class="window-col" style="padding: 0px;height:150px;line-height:0px;width: 100px;" id="window-col-0-1">
        <div id="img-bg-1" class="img-bg"></div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="window-col" style="padding: 0px;height:150px;line-height:0px;width:100px;" id="window-col-0-2">
        <div id="img-bg-2" class="img-bg"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="window-row-1" class="window-row">
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="window-col" style="padding: 0px;height:150px;line-height:0px;width:150px;" id="window-col-1-0">
        <div id="img-bg-0" class="img-bg"></div>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="1" colspan="1" class="window-col" style="padding: 0px;height:150px;line-height:0px;width:150px;" id="window-col-1-1">
        <div id="img-bg-1" class="img-bg"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've found out that increasing the middle column to 150px would give the expected result of it looking as it was 100px, but this is not an option since the values is going to be typed in dynamically.

What is the reason of this happening, and what would be the correct way of solving it ?

Answer (score 0):

We can use a table-layout property of css here.

`table{
table-layout:fixed;
}`

> The table and column widths are set by the widths of table and col or
>   by the width of  the first row of cells. Cells in other rows do not
>   affect column widths. If no widths are present on the first row, the
>   column widths are divided equally across the table, regardless of
>   content inside the cells.

So you do not need to set any width for column, its automatically calculated by table width & column used in rows.

You can find more on https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp